# I can't seem to figure out how to find the inverse of 22 mod 26

Tags: modules

I'm trying to learn how to do 2x2 hill ciphers, but I'm stuck. Through Euclidean' s algorithm I got `0=4-2*2=4-2(22-5*4)` down to `-13*22+11*26`. The problem is when I multiply 13 by my key [1/2 3/2], it simplifies to [13/0 13/0] and none of my plaintext is what it should be. I saw somewhere that you can only take the inverse if it's a coprime but then what am I supposed to do?

Thank you to everyone who responded, sorry I'm new to this website so I did a few things wrong. I researched more and I think a better way to ask my question is what do I do when decrypting a 2x2 hill cipher and the determinant is a number that you can't inverse mod 26.

Comment: Why is your key a vector?  It should be a $2 \times 2$ matrix.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Yes, $22$ is not invertible mod $26$, because $\gcd(22,26)=2\gt1$.  Your tag is inappropriate

Comment: Also, what are you trying to do, encrypt a message?  Decrypt?  If decrypting, you should provide your key matrix and ciphervector.  Yes, you need to invert your key matrix, so you'll need the determinant, etc.....

Comment: The math in your question does not display the way you intended. Try MathJax instead: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: I understand the how the equation works, but how do I know when to use it, and what do I do if I can't use it.